# what might cause the last value in .push to be dropped?

Tags: javascript

I've got the following JavaScript being built on the fly via a PHP foreach loop. I can see it as-is in the source code. However, when I run it in my application the last alert comes back undefined. It should read 100. Furthermore, a console.log(pr) only returns 4 values stored in the nested arrays (0-3).

Does anyone have any idea as to what might be going wrong? I'm not getting any errors to console and I can clearly see the value in the push statement.

```
pr = [];

pr.push([12, 'p1', 1, 24, 100]);
pr.push([13, 'p2', 1, 48, 200]);
pr.push([14, 'p3', 1, 72, 300]);
pr.push([15, 'p4', 1, 96, 400]);

alert( pr[0][2] );
alert( pr[0][3] );
alert( pr[0][4] );
```

The same code works just fine [running at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T4rUH/).

Comment: Are you altering the **pr** array anywhere else in your application? It could be quite possible you've deleted **pr[0][4]**. Is that javascript loading synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: As the code does works fine at jsfiddle. The bug must be hiding somewhere else, so you'll have to share more of the code.

Comment: I'm loading synchronously. Also there is very little chance of any changes before I'm calling the alert. Just to be safe I'll drop a console.log(pr) in the foreach statement.

Comment: @blue, I stand corrected. You're on to something. I don't know how/why I'd be deleting pr[0][4] but my last test proved it true. I can see the last console.log() in the foreach loop is outputting array[5] where as the the very next console log outputs an array[4].

Comment: @blue, if you want to post an answer I'll accept it. You were right. The code in question was being called twice. I've resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you altering the pr array anywhere else in your application? It could be quite possible you've deleted pr[0][4]. Is that javascript loading synchronously or asynchronously?